# Migrating MBean services from JBoss to WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, weblogic, weblogic11g

The company I work for is migrating to a new data center. We'll be using WebLogic instead of JBoss what we're using now.

I'm tasked with migrating the deployment (modifying ant scripts, ...etc) of some legacy J2EE applications (Apache Axis web services + Spring) and testing out their deployment on WebLogic.

As I'm digging through the legacy apps (which I didn't author or work on), I noticed they used JBoss MBean services...This is an area which I have almost zero knowledge of (with exception of things learned from few Google searches). I see in the XML configuration files something like

```
 <mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue"
     name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=jms.bla.blabla">
      <depends optional-attribute-   name="DestinationManager">jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager</depends>
     <depends optional-attribute-  name="SecurityManager">jboss.mq:service=SecurityManager</depends>^M
  ....etc
```

So, I decided I should do some research and learning to see how something like this can be migrated to WebLogic (11g). Can you PLEASE point me in the right direction on what I should be learning about to know how to migrate this?

Note: I never worked with JBoss MQ or any of it's APIs....

Thank you

Comment: Just wanted to ping you again and offer some support.  Feel free to contact me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell online this looks like this is a section of the jbossmq-destinations-service.xml file and is used to define destinations on JBoss (based on my research which may be inaccurate).  This would be the equivalent to defining JMS destinations in WebLogic.

I'm happy to help and provide you with a lot more resources.  You can reach me at jeffrey.west@oracle.com.  I'm interested in talking with you more about this migration effort.